# nodes near coords overrides only marks?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I'm trying to make a plot with labeled points and am seeing some strange behavior. I have
`\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.style={no markers, thick}}`
at the start of my document.

If I make a plot with `only marks`, the marks show up correctly, but if I have both `only marks` and `nodes near coords`, then the marks disappear. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.style={no markers, thick},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[domain=-1:1, only marks, samples=3]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[domain=-1:1, only marks, samples=3, nodes near coords]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output I get is below. Obviously, I can just put two `\addplot` commands in to get both, but is there a reason the second example doesn't do it?

[image]

Comment: remove `no markers` in `every axis plot/.style={no markers, thick},`  and it's better add `compat=1.18`

Comment: I have no markers in every axis plot/.style because I have a very long document with lots and lots of plots, and in almost all of them, I actually don't want markers. So, I'm really wanting to know how to override that in a particular plot.

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting `\pgfplotset` in a group with `{}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.style={no markers, thick},
  compat=1.18
}

\begin{document}


{%<--------- begin of the group
  \pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.style={thick},
}
With \verb|every axis plot/.style={thick},|

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[domain=-1:1, only marks, samples=3, nodes near coords]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%<--------- end of the group

By default

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[domain=-1:1, only marks, samples=3, nodes near coords]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```